# Tried with UI Test Case to run in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

```
import XCTest

class LoginUITest: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false

        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        app.launch()

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testExample() {
        app.buttons["Login – Button" ].tap()
        XCTAssertTrue(app.alerts["Login – Button"].exists)
    }


}
```

I have tried above code. but getting error.

No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"Login – Button" IN identifiers' from input {(

)}

Answer (score 1):

You've got error here 
`XCTAssertTrue(app.alerts["Login – Button"].exists)`

Change `app.alerts` to `app.buttons` and make sure that your button has the title `Login – Button`. You can create `identifier` (`button.identifier`) for the button and then use it: `app.buttons[YOUR_INDENTIFIER]`.

Comment: Hi i already set Login – Button accessibility identifier in storyboard with accessibility enabled. but getting above error on app.buttons["Login – Button" ].tap()

Comment: Looks everything ok. Debug and check what is a value for `app.buttons`.